# Как печатать постоянно обновляемое время работы функции

Tags: c++, qt, время

Как вывести в `QLabel` время работы функции, чтобы время постоянно обновлялось: До этого делал так:

```
QTime myTimer;                          // в начале функции засекаем время
int Milliseconds = myTimer.elapsed();   // в конце функции замеряем время ее работы.
emit(updateWorkTime(Milliseconds));     // передаем сигнал в слот другой функции

// В другой функции реализовываю в слоте отображение в метке
void MainWindow::updateWorkTime(int time)
{
    calculationControl->ui->label->setText(QString("%1").arg(time));
}
```

Однако тут будет отображаться только конечное время работы функции. А как сделать так, чтобы отображаемое время накапливалось и обновлялось прямо по ходу работы измеряемой функции?

Comment: Хотя emit - это всего лишь пустой макрос, но все же, принято писать: ``emit updateWorkTime(Milliseconds);``

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
QString uptimeToString(int ms) {
    // Без оптимизации, для понимания.
    const int days    = ms / 60 / 60 / 24;
    const int hours   = (ms / 60 / 60) % 24;
    const int minutes = (ms / 60) % 60;
    const int seconds = ms % 60;

    // В аргументах символ '0' будет подставлен к цифре,
    // если число от 0 до 9.
    const QString str
        = QString("%1 %2:%3:%4")
            .arg(days)
            .arg(hours,2,10,'0')
            .arg(minutes,2,10,'0')
            .arg(seconds,2,10,'0');

    return str;
}

void MainWindow::updateWorkTime(int time) {
    calculationControl->ui->label->setText(uptimeToString(time));
}
```

Comment: у типов QTime, QDate, QDateTime есть метод toString, в котором можно задать формат вывода, и не нужно изобретать таких велосипедов.

Comment: @Александр, всегда умиляло это желание отдельных индивидов пнуть соседа по поводу и без. Узбагойтесь. Не всегда что-то делается просто так.

Comment: пост дополнил, будьте добры посмотреть. привел 4 файла

Comment: @DavidRise, Вы уже написали комментарий под ответом Александра. Он обязательно получит уведомление об этом. И лучше удалите свой ответ, а код разместите непосредственно в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

mainwindow.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTime>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTime m_startTime;

    void updateTime(int _ms);
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTime>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    m_startTime = QTime::currentTime();
    updateTime(0);
    startTimer(1000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::updateTime(int _ms)
{
    QTime time = QTime(0,0,0).addMSecs(_ms);
    ui->label->setText(time.toString("hh:mm:ss"));
}

void MainWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *)
{
    int diffMs = m_startTime.msecsTo(QTime::currentTime());
    updateTime(diffMs);
}
```

Comment: В данный момент нужно передать время работы функции в потоке в другой виджет к которму мы обращаемся в mainWindow набросок функции привел ниже.

Answer (score 0):

В данный момент нужно передать время работы функции в потоке в другой виджет к которму мы обращаемся в mainWindow набросок функции привел ниже. Из потока thread.cpp в главный поток MainWindow

1. thread.h

   ```
   #ifndef THREAD_H
   #define THREAD_H

   #include <QThread>
   #include <QTime>
   #include <QTimer>
   #include <global.h>
   #include <lbd_manager.h>
   #include <ballistic.h>


   class Thread : public QThread
   {
       Q_OBJECT

   public:
       explicit Thread(manager_lbd::ManagerLbd * lbd, Ballistic * ballisticCalc, QObject *parent = 0);

       int IDPLidThread;
       bool closeDialog;

   protected:
       void run();

   signals:
       void sendMessageGuiKA(int);
       void sendMessageGuiZRV(int);
       void sendCloseGui(bool);
       void sendTimeCalculation(int);

   private:
       manager_lbd::ManagerLbd * dbManager;
       Ballistic * ballistic;
   };

   #endif // THREAD_H
   ```
2. thread.cpp

   ```
   #include "thread.h"

   Thread::Thread(manager_lbd::ManagerLbd * lbd, Ballistic * ballisticCalc,   QObject *parent) : QThread(parent)
   {
       dbManager = lbd;
       ballistic = ballisticCalc;
   }

   void Thread::run()
   {
       mAssert(ballistic);
       mAssert(dbManager);

       // замеряем вначале
       QTime myTimer;
       myTimer.start();


       //
       // ТУТ большой расчёт с циклами и тд время которого нужно замерять.
       // который нужно выводить в label который находится mainWindow  в поле класа calculationControl->ui->label выводить постоянно каждую секунду и милисекунды с обновлением label
       //


       // время конца расчёта передаем в MainWindow
       int nMilliseconds = myTimer.elapsed();
       emit(sendTimeCalculation(nMilliseconds));


       // передаем сигнал, что расчёт закончен, а значит пора закрыть окно.
       closeDialog = true;
       emit(sendCloseGui(closeDialog));
   }
   ```
3. mainwindow.h

   ```
   #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
   #define MAINWINDOW_H

   #include <QMainWindow>
   #include <QPushButton>

   #include "calcprogressdialog.h"
   #include "ballistic.h"
   #include "thread.h"

   // Менеджеры соединения с БД
   #include "lbd_manager.h"
   // Глобальные настройки и параметры
   #include "global.h"

   namespace Ui {
       class MainWindow;
   }

   class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
   {
   Q_OBJECT

   public slots:
       void runCalculation();
       void reciveSendGuiKa(int Ka);
       void reciveSendGuiZrv(int Zrv);
       void CancelThread();
       void reciveTimeCalculation(int time);

   private:
       manager_lbd::ManagerLbd *dbManager;
       CalcProgressDialog *calculationControl;
       Ballistic *ballistic;
       Thread *thread;

       Ui::MainWindow *ui;
   };

   #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
   ```
4. mainwindow.cpp

   ```
   #include <QHBoxLayout>
   #include <QMessageBox>
   #include <QComboBox>
   #include <QGroupBox>
   #include <QTreeWidget>

   #include "mainwindow.h"
   #include "ui_mainwindow.h"


   // TODO: Неправильное решение, переделать!
   #include "ui_planeditwidget.h"
   #include "ui_calculationdata.h"
   #include "ui_calcprogressdialog.h"

   MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
       QMainWindow(parent),
       ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
   {
       ui->setupUi(this);

       dbManager = new manager_lbd::ManagerLbd(this);
       calculationControl = new CalcProgressDialog(this);
       ballistic = new Ballistic(this);
       thread = new Thread(dbManager,ballistic);

       // Запуск расчёта
       connect(this->planEditWidget->ui->pushButton_toCalculation, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(runCalculation()));
       // Отмена расчёта
       connect(calculationControl->ui->pushButton_cancel,SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(CancelThread()));

   }

   MainWindow::~MainWindow()
   {
       delete ui;
   }


   void MainWindow::reciveSendGuiKa(int Ka)
   {
       // Получаем КА и по одному отдаём их в метод расчёта
       calculationControl->ui->label->setText("Расчёт интервалов прохождения РЦР...");
       calculationControl->ui->progressBar->setValue(0);
       calculationControl->ui->progressBar->setValue(calculationControl->ui->progressBar->value()+Ka);
       qDebug() << "testGuiKA" << Ka;
   }

   void MainWindow::reciveSendGuiZrv(int Zrv)
   {
       // Получаем КА и по одному отдаём их в метод расчёта
       calculationControl->ui->label->setText("Расчёт ЗРВ...");
       calculationControl->ui->progressBar->setValue(0);
       calculationControl->ui->progressBar->setValue(calculationControl->ui->progressBar->value()+Zrv);
       qDebug() << "testGuiZrv" << Zrv;
   }

   void MainWindow::CancelThread()
   {
       // TODO: нужно закрывать окно при нажатии в интерфейсе кнопки ОТМЕНА (пока не работает)
       calculationControl->close();
       if(thread->isRunning())
       {
          thread->quit();
          thread->wait();
          thread->deleteLater();
       }
   }

   void MainWindow::reciveCloseGui(bool closeDialog)
   {
       if (closeDialog == true)
       {
           calculationControl->close();
       }
   }

   void MainWindow::reciveTimeCalculation(int time)
   {
       calculationControl->ui->label_old->update();
       calculationControl->ui->label_old->setText(QString("%1").arg(time));
       calculationControl->ui->label_old->update();
       qDebug() << time;
   }



   // Запуск расчёта
   void MainWindow::runCalculation()
   {
       calculationControl->show();
       connect(thread, SIGNAL(sendMessageGuiKA(int)), this, SLOT(reciveSendGuiKa(int)));
       connect(thread, SIGNAL(sendMessageGuiZRV(int)), this, SLOT(reciveSendGuiZrv(int)));
       connect(thread, SIGNAL(sendCloseGui(bool)), this, SLOT(reciveCloseGui(bool)));
       connect(thread, SIGNAL(sendTimeCalculation(int)), this, SLOT(reciveTimeCalculation(int)));
       // connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

       thread->start(QThread::HighestPriority);
       qDebug() << "test1";


       //calculationControl->close();

       //loadAllIDPl();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Замерять время выполнения внутри функции расчета и постоянно плеваться сигналами о текущем времени не оптимально. Правильнее отнаследовать виджет от QLabel, в котором при вызове слота `start()` будет запускаться таймер с обновлением времени. При окончании расчета остановить таймер и вывести полученное из функции расчета время.
Как-то так:

TimeLabel.cpp

```
#include "timelabel.h"

TimeLabel::TimeLabel(QWidget *parent) : QLabel(parent)
{

}

void TimeLabel::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *e)
{
    setText(QTime(0,0).addMSecs(time.elapsed()).toString("m:ss.zzz"));  //эту конструкцию лучше обернуть в отдельную функцию и сделать нормальный выбор формата вывода
}

void TimeLabel::start()
{
    //TODO проверить, не запущен ли уже таймер, отреагировать
    time.restart();
    timerID = startTimer(100);  //запоминаем идентификатор запущенного таймера чтобы потом можно было его прибить
}

void TimeLabel::stop(int ms)    //сюда можно передать время работы функции и оно будет выведено в качестве текста
{
    killTimer(timerID);
    if (ms > 0)
        setText(QTime(0,0).addMSecs(ms).toString("m:ss.zzz"));
}
```

TimeLabel.h

```
#ifndef TIMELABEL_H
#define TIMELABEL_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QTime>

class TimeLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TimeLabel(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *e);

private:
    int timerID;
    QTime time;

signals:

public slots:
    void start();
    void stop(int ms = 0);
};

#endif // TIMELABEL_H
```

При этом подходе таких лейблов можно напихать на форму хоть сто и мониторить время выполнения чего угодно. Перед началом расчета вызвать `ui->label->start()`, после окончания вызвать (сигналом, или напрямую) `stop`, передав время выполнения функици, или почистить текст, по необходимости.